# Nothing happening when I click Post Comment button (ThinksterIO:Real Time Webapps tutorial)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I ran into another snag while going through the ThinksterIO Learn to Build Real Time Webapps tutorial around the 90% mark where one is shown how to add and delete comments:

https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/learn-to-build-realtime-webapps/#adding-comments-functionality-to-the-post-service-9

Every time I click the Post Comment button absolutely nothing happen and I simply can't figure it out. I am expecting some kind of error to show up but nil. It's as if the button is not hooked up to the function. I was so frustrated that I eventually just copy and pasted the code from the tutorial to make sure I had it down right. Even after doing that it still didn't work.

I've created a Plunker with this app running over here http://embed.plnkr.co/OhzDTU/preview

You can sign in with the email `user@user.com` and `1234` password. You will then be able to try to comment on posts. Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

### UPDATE

I took away the user `user@user.com` and `1234` password since problem is now fixed.

Comment: Hi there! This is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is a code dump asking us to debug. But there's not enough info here (e.g. the exact line of code failing or the actual error stack), nor can we take this fragmented code sample and run it to reproduce the error. Would you mind narrowing the scope here to something small that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @kato ok I have created a Plunker that includes all the files to my app over here http://embed.plnkr.co/bYeQnt/preview Or perhaps I should make it smaller?

Comment: The plunker you've created does not produce the error above when I try to add a comment. It doesn't work; clicking the button does nothing; but no error is thrown to the console.

Comment: @Kato Yeah I am so sorry about that. I did not double check the code. It turns out I changed something in the code at some point. I rewrote the entire post to reflect my current problem which is that absolutely nothing is happening when the Post Comment button is clicked. This is rare and strange for me as I have always had errors show up before. I am just completely perplexed at why nothing is happening. It's as if the button is not connected at all to the `addComment()` function.

Comment: Your add comment button is in showpost.html, which is rendered by PostViewCtrl. However, your addComment method is attached to the scope of PostsCtrl (it doesn't exist when you try to click it). I don't think that you can get an error for this.

Comment: @Kato feel free to provide an answer to the question if you'd like and thanks again :) not only for helping me with this problem but also teaching me how to better ask questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add comment button is in `showpost.html`, which is rendered by `PostViewCtrl`. However, your `addComment` method is attached to the scope of `PostsCtrl` (it doesn't exist when you try to click it). The simplest answer here is just to move addComment() over to the other controller.

Regarding the lack of error messages, I don't think that you can get an error for this. I had a look at the docs for $log and tried to decide if you could add some debugging output, but it looks like it's already on (i.e. the lack of a method seems to fail silently).

About your only option here is to try something like `{{addComment|json}}` in the view to see if it exists, but you'd first have to suspect that it didn't.